# Internals of signal handling

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, signals, ipc

I have been studying [this excellent Caltech](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/%7Edonnie/cs124/lectures/CS124Lec14.pdf) lecture regarding the signal delivery mechanism, which talks about how current process state (stack, RIP etc) at the time of the signal generation is copied, then updated to jump to the signal handler, then restored afterwards so we resume at the interrupt point.  I then read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/gen-16/index.html), which states

> Dealing with asynchronous signals is more complicated than dealing
> with synchronous signals.

Now whereas I understand the basic difference between synchronous and asynchronous signals (self generated vs sent from another process), I would like to know if the process I have outlined above, and talked about in depth on the Caltech lecture, is for asynchronous, synchronous, or both: I am thinking its for asynchronous, since it is quite complicated, but then cannot see how synchronous handling would be much different.

Can someone please clarify?

*(And yes, I have searched PAQs and have found nothing: it took me long enough to find the Caltech lecture!)*

Comment: I've never seen this use of "asynchronous signal" before! Do you have other sources than Oracle?

Comment: I don't, that's the only site I found which talked about it being more complicated.  Are you suggesting that it is *not* more complicated, and what I outlined is the process for for both types of signal?

Comment: I'll say that the site isn't very *good* as it doesn't explain its claims. When a singular source claims something that they don't back, you are allowed to doubt :) All in all, if your OS knows how to context-switch, all these signal handlers are pretty much the same level of complexity: you save state, you jump, you execute, you restore state, you jump back. Your OS does that several thousand times a second – that's what makes "multiprocessing" with more processes than CPU cores work.

Comment: I mean, in that "multithreaded programming guide"; go into the table of contents -> [book info](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/book-info/index.html), and the [preface](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h0322/index.html); this book is *dated*. The most modern literature it cites is from 1993. What seemed daunting tasks to application developers some 25 years ago might not be "very complicated" today. A lot of the things described in the book are just really very 1980s!

Comment: (especially, also: your question definitely asks about [tag:linux-kernel] things, and that book is older than the linux kernel, probably, and doesn't concern itself with it at all)